# How to support (a = b) = c?

Tags: c++

Question 1> what does the following code meaning and what the order of assignment is?

```
ClassName a1, a2, a3;
a1 = a2 = a3;
```

Does it mean to First assign value of a3 to a2 and then assign ?? to a1.

Question 2> what does the following code meaning?

```
ClassName a1, a2, a3;
(a1 = a2) = a3;
```

Question 3> 
Given a class as follows:

```
class A
{
   ...
}
```

What operators have to be defined in order to support the following operation?

```
A a1, a2, a3;
(a1 = a2) = a3;
```

Comment: Just reading these sorts of questions makes me resolve never to use such syntax.

Comment: @David, I don't like those either:) +1

Comment: For the third question, although it will compile as-is, you probably want to overload
`A& A::operator=(const A& other) {myvar = other.myvar; return *this;}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Question 1**

This:

```
a1 = a2 = a3;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
a1 = (a2 = a3);
```

For primitive types, or for PODs, this is equivalent to:

```
a2 = a3;
a1 = a2;
```

For user-defined types, it's equivalent to:

```
a1.operator=(a2.operator=(a3));
```

If you don't define your own overloads of `operator=`, then this will be the same as for the primitive types.

**Question 2**

This:

```
(a1 = a2) = a3;
```

only works for user-defined types.  It is equivalent to:

```
a1.operator=(a2).operator=(a3);
```

If you use the compiler-provided operators, then this is equivalent to:

```
a1 = a2;
a1 = a3;
```

**Question 3**

No operators have to be defined, as the compiler provides a copy-assignment operator implementation if you don't write your own.

Comment: "which is equivalent to this: `a2 = a3; a1 = a2;`" assuming a sensible implementation of `operator=`. If `ClassName::operator=` is user-defined to return a reference to something other than `a2`, that's not sensible but it breaks the equivalence...

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1:**

Evaluation order is performed from right to left, so `a1 = a2 = a3` is equivalent to `a2 = a3; a1 = a2;`

**Question 2:**

If `operator=` has not been redefined, it means `a1 = a3`.

**Question 3:**

Nothing, it works as is.

Comment: Probably you mean to say **Overloaded** not **Redefined**